# Copying attachments from one geodatabase to another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, file-geodatabase, attachments

I have a file geodatabase that is a compilation of multiple file geodatabases with varying schemas.

Some feature classes in the original databases had attachments, however the attachment tables no longer exist in the new, combined geodatabase.

There is an "Old-ObjectID" field for features in the new geodatabase that represents the ObjectID of the feature as it was in the original geodatabases.

I would like to know if there is some way to re-relate the old attachment tables to the new ObjectIDs in the new geodatabase?

Comment: You have first download attachments to disk. After this - attach them to new feature class

Comment: Can the attachments, or BLOB objects, in the old tables be linked using a standard Table Join with your "Old-ObjectID"? If not, with what @FelixIP was saying, to download your attachments follow these links: [1](http://www.cloudpointgeo.com/blog/blog/2014/3/5/getting-attachments-down-from-arcgis-online) [2](http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41763). The relevant python function to save a BLOB byte stream is `f.write(attachment.tobytes())`.

Comment: John, the field  "Old-ObjectID" is a field within the attribute table of the feature class. I can join the attribute table of the new feature class to the old attachment table (join based on REL_OBJECTID = OLD_OBJECTID). Then I try to field calculate the REL_OBJECTID field to the OBJECTID field of the new feature class. However, here I get lost because the REL_OBJECTID reverts back to the original OBJECTID. I was hoping just to update the REL_OBJECTID field to reflect the new OBJECTIDs in the new geodatabase and then copy the old attachment table to a new attach. table in the new geodatabase

Comment: Does the above make sense to try and do or am a way off base here?

Comment: Your approach sounded good and made sense except when you said the calculated field reverts back to the original objectid. This doesn't sound right. Get the new ID into the field then append the attachments to the new table.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.